# XSane Image scanner cannot find Epson WF-4630

Tags: networking, scanner, sane, xsane

XSane Image Scanner and Simple Scan cannot find the printer/scanner/copier I've been using for 4 years. The printer works fine. It's connected to my home network via wifi. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's the result of `sudo sane-find-scanner`:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

This is the result of `sane-find-scanner`:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

I've ensured that `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` has epson2 uncommented.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so I don't know if you have installed ImageScan that Epson releases; you would get it from here http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=1.0.4 and for 64bit Ubuntu you would download iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb.tar.gz which Epson call an iscan bundle so it should be able to configure for you; the guide to ImageScan can be found here http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html

Comment: Nisse Engstrom - thanks for the tip. I will be trying this next. The answer below, while not solving the problem, has pointed me in the correct direction.  Once again you advice is appreciated.

Comment: @NvrEnuff: I think you meant to address pdc. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

network scanning needs a little configuring for epson.

First be sure that `net` is uncommented in /etc/sane.d/dll.config
Second /etc/sane.d/dll.d/iscan should read `epkowa`
Third add `net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf. replace the x's with the IP address of your scanner.

I'm not sure if this applies to all systems, but in my case the printer needs to be awake before you can scan. iscan will not wake a sleeping printer.

Comment: ravery - your answer did get me to having my scanner recognized, however one more step was required. I edited /etc/sane.d/epson2.conf to include net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and commented out Autodetect. Many thanks!

Comment: @NvrEnuff -- ah, your driver used a different config file than mine.

Comment: Hmm... I do not have any file `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`! I am seeing a mixture of advice to use `epson2` vs `epkowa` so I'm not sure if I need to figure out how to fix this. Epson's instructions mention neither.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my problem was not with any configuration settings. It was my router. I updated  the firmware and that started the whole problem. I was using a Linksys WRT 3200 ACM. There was multiple problems with the firmware. So much so Linksys sent another router (EAS 300). Definitiely a step down, but at least it works. Linksys claims they fixed the firmware now. I still haven't sat down to re-intall the original router.